# Possible to have a "dependently typed" field in a pydantic class?

Tags: python, types, python-3.8, pydantic

I wonder if, and then how, in `pydantic`, one could have a field whose type is determined by the value of another field, e.g., as follows:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Example(BaseModel):
    type: str
    value: MyType[type] # not possible and wrong syntax, but ...
```

Let's say I want to have instances with int or complex:

```
ex1 = Example(type="int", value = 5) # or maybe MyType("int",5)
ex2 = Example(type="complex", value=1+2j) # or maybe MyType("complex", 1+2j)
```

Then I want `ex1.value` to be validated as an integer, and `ex2.value` as a complex. Ultimately I want multidimensional lists (`T`, `List[T]`, `List[List[T]]`, etc.) carrying (where `T` is) `int`, `float`, `complex`, or `str`.

Is there a nice way of doing something in that direction? (preferably in Python 3.8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this work for you?

```
from pydantic.generics import GenericModel
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, TYPE_CHECKING

T = TypeVar('T')

class Example(GenericModel, Generic[T]):
    value: T

ex1 = Example[int](value=5)
ex2 = Example[complex](value=1+2j)

if TYPE_CHECKING:
    reveal_type(ex1.value)
    reveal_type(ex2.value)
```

Output:

```
$ mypy program.py
program.py:13: note: Revealed type is "builtins.int"
program.py:14: note: Revealed type is "builtins.complex"
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

If you want to have a type attribute you can add it like this:

```
from pydantic.generics import GenericModel
from typing import Generic, Type, TypeVar, TYPE_CHECKING

T = TypeVar('T')

class Example(GenericModel, Generic[T]):
    type: Type[T]
    value: T

ex1 = Example[int](type=int, value=5)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it looks promising! I'll try it out :-)

Comment: Hi again, I almost got it working as I want, but when I put
`TestGenerics[List[float]](type=List[float], value=[1.9,8.0])`
I get the error
`E   pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for TestGenerics[List[float]]
E   type
E     a class is expected (type=type_error.class)`
however, when I put `type=list`, it works. Probably I need to express it differently for parameterized types such as `List[T]` ?

Comment: Yeah, the issue is python doesn't understand `List[float]` in runtime, may be in python 3.10+ (`list[float]`), this would not be an issue. However, since you can ensure the validation using `TestGenerics[List[float]](...)`, maybe you can consider using `type: str` and passing `TestGenerics[List[float]](type='List[float]', value=[1.9,8.0])`. Can't think of anything better at the moment.

Comment: Yes, that sounds reasonable. Thanks!